# how to show wiki markup text in reactjs project?

Tags: reactjs, wiki, markup, wikitext

I scraped some Wikipedia pages and want to show them in my private web page. My private webpage written in reactJS, so I wonder if there is a lib/method to load and show wiki text/wiki markup in reactJS.

Comment: Have you tried using the wikipedia API?

Comment: I just glimpse the wikipedia API, maybe it's not what I need. I already got one entity's attribute and value, but the value is in the format of wikitext. how to show them friendly in my web page is my concern.